# Infinitiv Präsens oder Perfekt: »...ohne seinen Absender anzugeben/angegeben zu haben«

Tags: infinitive, tense

In *Die Gelbe Aktuell* ist im Lösungsschlüssel der folgende Satz zu finden:

> Er schickte die Bestellung ab, ohne seinen Absender anzugeben.

Soweit ich weiß, wird Infinitiv Perfekt gebraucht, wenn eine Situation einer anderen vorangeht. Warum lautet der Satz also nicht »ohne seinen Absender angegeben zu haben«? Der zweite Teil des Satzes ist doch früher passiert.

Comment: Wieso "seinen"? Die Bestellung => ihren Absender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erstmal muss man anmerken, dass wenn eine Situation oder Aktion einer anderen vorangeht und beide in der Vergangenheit liegen, so ist das [Plusquamperfekt zu verwenden](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/zeitformen/plusquamperfekt).

> Er schickte die Bestellung ab, **hatte** jedoch zuvor nicht seinen Absender angegeben.
>   Er schickte die Bestellung ab, ohne dass er vorher seinen Absender angegeben **hatte**.

Von dem Standpunkt betrachtet, wäre das Perfekt falsch.

Nun ist aber beides richtig, das Perfekt und das Präsens. Eine grammatische korrekte Begründung kann ich hier nicht liefern, aber zumindest einen gedanklichen Ansatz, wie man sich die Richtigkeit herleiten kann.

Den zweiten Teil des Satzes kannst du hier entweder als Fakt betrachten. Und Fakten werden im Präsens angegeben, sofern sie noch Gültigkeit haben. (Bsp. Licht breitet sich aus. -> Fakt, Präsens)
Oder du betrachtest die ganze Aktion (Brief schreiben, Brief adressieren, Absender angeben, Brief abschicken) als ein Gesamtes, so ist also das Angeben des Absenders ein Teil einer Handlung zum Zeitpunkt X und eben nicht zuvor.

Beachte hierzu nun, dass der zweite Teil des Satzes zeitlich in relativer Abhängigkeit zum ersten Teil steht. Es ist ein Fakt, der zum Zeitpunkt X wahr war und dieser Zeitpunkt X ist gedanklich unsere Gegenwart.

```
Zeitpunkt X in der Vergangenheit | Fakt gültig zum Zeitpunkt X
Er schickte die Bestellung ab,     ohne den Absender anzugeben.
```

Alternativ kannst du im zweiten Teil des Satzes natürlich auch erkenntlich machen, dass die Handlung zuvor passiert ist. Auch hier aber aus der Sichtweise, dass der Zeitpunkt X als Gegenwart angesehen wird.

```
Zeitpunkt X in der Vergangenheit | Fakt vor 'gegenwärtigem' Zeitpunkt X
Er schickte die Bestellung ab,     ohne den Absender angegeben zu haben.
```

Wie erwähnt, ist das keine Erklärung die Hand und Fuß hat, aber es sollte dem Verständnis hoffentlich dennoch helfen. Ich habe versucht, etwas im Internet zu finden, aber mehr als [ein weiteres Beispiel auf Canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/Infinitiv.html) konnte ich nicht finden. (Bei dem Beispiel dort ("Er packte das Geschenk, ohne sich beim Großvater dafür zu bedanken.") sind die beiden Handlungen zur exakt gleichen Zeit, dass entspricht etwa dem Ansatz oben, die gesamte Prozedur als eine ganze Handlung zu betrachten.)

Comment: Wieso "seinen"? Die Bestellung => ihren Absender.

Answer (score 6):

Beides wäre richtig.

Sofern das Angeben des Absenders als Teil der Handlung *Abschicken* angesehen werden kann, ist der Gebrauch des Präsens auch nicht unüblich.

> Er schickte die Bestellung ab, ohne **(dabei)** den Absender anzugeben.

Präsens erlaubt hier eine einfachere Satzstruktur.
Wenn man das Abschicken (in den Briefkasten stecken?) vom Absenderangeben trennt, ist Perfekt sinnvoller.

> Er schickte die Bestellung ab, ohne **(vorher)** den Absender angegeben zu haben.